# Что я делаю неправильно в KeyEvent?

Tags: java

я ещё совсем новичок в Джаве, и для своей игры - Тетрис хотел сделать управления стрелочками для сдвига фигуры вправо, или же влево.

Но после создания switch условия для перемещения фигуры, ничего не произошло.
Если не будет достаточно кода, приведённого ниже, могу скинуть ссылку на сам код.

```
public void fallingFigure(KeyEvent e) {
            switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
                case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT: {
                    xfigure1 += 20;
                } break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT: {
                    xfigure1 -=20;
                } break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: А почему у вас break за пределами скобок? Уберите скобки вообще, они здесь не нужны, насколько я знаю.

Comment: возможно глупый вопрос, но мало ли...этот код зарегистрирован как обработчик события?

Comment: kami, ну вообще, да, так как нужно считывать, нажата клавиша или нет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот часть кода из моего тетриса:

```
        screen.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
                case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                    plx = 1;
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                    plx = -1;
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                    down = true;
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE:
                    isGame = true;
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE:
                    pause = !pause;
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_DELETE:
                    isGame = false;
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_R:
                    turn = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
```

`screen` - это JLabel, на котором я отрисовываю игру